# Cypress wait until Saving window disappears

Tags: cypress, assertion

In Cypress as a part of test case I have an action, when Cypress clicks the Save button and then a Saving window appears with text Saving.

The only thing I want, is to wait until this alert disappears.

I have this:

```js
cy.contains('button:visible','Save').should('not.be.disabled')
  .trigger('click', { force: true });  

cy.wait(2000)
cy.contains('Saving').should('not.exist');
```

However this seems working and in test runner it is green and passes, in the last step it says `expected undefined not to exists in the DOM`

[image]

Why is there undefined, if it should look for Saving? Or it is because of `cy.wait(2000)` so that the alert disappears during this time and Cypress doesn't catch it in next step?

But still I think it should say expected **Saving** not to exists in the DOM, not **undefined**.

Comment: Have you tested your theory by removing the `cy.wait(2000)`?

Comment: *Why is there undefined, if it should look for Saving* - well if it found "Saving" then the next part would fail. I think it used to say something related to the search expression, but the queries were split off from commands recently and this is definitely different to the previous log (although it is logical, is not informative). I'd suggest raising it on the Cypress site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug introduced by the separation of "query" commands from other commands in Cypress v12.

In previous versions, this is the log

[image]

You should raise an issue with Cypress to get it fixed.

In the meantime here is a hack that will pull the selector from the previous log entry, assuming you need to have the log corrected for documentation purposes.

```js
Cypress.on('log:changed', (data, log) => {
  if (data.message.startsWith('expected **undefined**')) {
    const previousLog = cy.$$(`.commands-container li.command-name-contains .command-message-text`, top?.document)
    const selector = previousLog.text()
    const currentLog = cy.$$(`.commands-container li.command-name-assert .command-message-text`, top?.document)
    currentLog[0].innerText = currentLog[0].innerText.replace('undefined', `**${selector}**`)
  }
})
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I was sure it worked in the past as you wrote!

Answer (score 3):

The first thing that is missing IMO is ***then a Saving window appears*** - you do not confirm this in the test, so perhaps the test is confirming it does not exist *before* it has appeared.

```js
cy.contains('button:visible','Save').should('not.be.disabled').trigger('click', { force: true });
cy.contains('Saving').should('exist')  
cy.contains('Saving').should('not.exist')
```

The second thing is, the "window" may be a browser-generated alert in which case you can't confirm it with javascript at all.

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work. Now it also says: assert: expected undefined to exist in the DOM

Comment: when I remove cy.wait command, and add your solution, then the saving exists works fine, but not exists is again undefined: assert expected <h2#swal2-title.swal2-title> to exist in the DOM /containsSaving assert expected undefined not to exist in the DOM

Comment: Why are you adding your wait into this answer? The point is to remove the wait by testing properly.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use here cy.waitUntil() function the following way where you can pass such arguments as timeout to make sure your test will not hang forever and interval of checking that element doesn't exist:

```
  cy.waitUntil(
    () => cy.contains('Saving').should('not.exist'),
    {
      timeout: 60000,
      interval: 1000,
    }
  );
```

Comment: Using `cy.waitUntil()` isn't really needed. You can pass a timeout parameter directly into `cy.contains('Saving', { timeout: 6000 })`. The assertion `.should('not.exist')` will already automatically retry until the condition passes.

Comment: Agree with you that it can be implemented with cy.contains() but personally for me cy.waitUntil looks more descriptive for me and, what is more, not sure that interval can be used in cy.contains()

Comment: and what is cy.waitUntil ?  cy.waitUntil is not a function

Comment: when I use cy.contains('Saving', { timeout: 6000 }) it is expecting to find Saving, if there is no Saving, then the test fails - Timed out retrying after 6000ms: Expected to find content: 'Saving' but never did. Because it disappears in a milisecond after clicking the Save button, but in other cases it might be saving for a minute, so I need to check, if the Saving window is still there, then wait, otherwise continue testing

Answer (score 0):

ok, so I tried it now with simple:

```
cy.get('body').should('not.contain', 'Saving');
```

and it seems working.

[image]

If there is still Saving window, it will wait some seconds, if not, it passes.

The issue might be, that `cy.contains` gets only one DOM element, and as the saving is in swal alert, it is another DOM element, so it shows undefined I think.

However strange is, that `cy.contains('Saving').should('exist')`  is recognized even if it is another DOM element

Comment: What do you mean "another DOM"? Are you trying to say "another element"?